# Find a file in specific folders in Python

Tags: python

I have 5 folders, `1,2,3,4,5`. I want to know which folders don't have the file `Data.csv` in them. Is there a straightforward way to do it?

```
N=5
for i in range(1,N+1):
    file_loc = f"C:\\Users\\{i}\\Data.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.path.exists` to check if the provided path exists or not. Also on a side note, instead of manually adding `\\` in the path, you can use `os.path.join`

```py
import os
N=5
for i in range(1,N+1):
    file_loc = os.path.join("C:\\", "Users", str(i), "Data.csv")
    if not os.path.exists(file_loc):
        print(i)
```

Comment: It prints ```True
True
True
False
True```. I want it to print ```i``` corresponding to ```False```. In this case, ```i=4```

Comment: `os.path.exists(file_loc)` returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the provided path exists or not. So, you need to print `i` for `False` value

Comment: I thought you can take from there, anyways, have updated the answer, you basically needed to print `i` condtionally using `if` condition.

Comment: Shoul be `print(file_loc)` instead of `print(i)`

Comment: @RadekRojík OP said he wanted to print `i`, you can look at the first comment in the answer

Comment: Yes, my bad. You're right.